# CSS transition - Disappear and appear again

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to create responsive menu

1) big screen shows top navigation

2) small screen becomes off-canvas menu

I'm using flex box and I'm able to roughly achieve what I want using React + CSS

I'm able to transition the menu and the main container to move on toggle
BUT my toggle button is behaving weirdly, it can transition out, but when toggle to false, it disappears a little before appearing at the correct position

Ive put my code on sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-tree-nx4gm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

change your css like

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
 .navbar.show {
    width: 250px;
    opacity: 1;
 }
}
```